# Apache serves "/" but 404 all other url

Tags: php, apache

I built a php site using the built in server. I experienced none of the problems I am now facing when using Apache.

Folder structure:

**app**
-> index.php

**controllers**
-> home.php

**views**
-> home.php

I have Apache successfully serving the home page at "/" but any other page I visit returns a 404. Inside "index.php" is a "switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])" statement. A visit to the URI called the controller which in turn calls the view:

```
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
{
  case '/':
    home_controller::home();
    break;

  case '/signup':
    signup_controller::signup();
    break;
}
```

If I try to visit the "signup page" at "/signup" I get a 404. I'm not sure why this is the case. I don't know Apache that well but spent a lot of time trying to figure this out. Rewrite didn't fix the problem but I could have been doing it wrong. Any information would be much appreciated.

**Edit 1**
Modrewrite may solve the problem but it did not before. As stated I don't know Apache that well so finding the correct terminology may be tripping me up.

My PHP program takes the REQUEST_URI and has a router built in that matches on a switch statement. My logic was that any uri that goes to Apache would in turn go to PHP. I did nothing to make "/" work correctly. Not sure why I need to do something different to make "/signup" work.

**Edit 2**

I solved the problem.

```
try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
```

I switched from Apache to Nginx and applied the line above. I was actually having two issues. The first was a database problem stopping the app from functioning correctly. The other was the line missing above.

This question was not a duplicate as "pretty urls" was not the answer. The problem was how Apache was routing my already made urls in php.

Thanks ippi for providing the link!

Comment: Why should Apache serve anything other than a 404 for `/signup`? Have you don't anything to route that URL to your PHP program?

Comment: See edit 1. I will look again more closely at the link.

Comment: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html (Same info as the duplicate one, but the info is more condensed I think! Aimed at slim, but works for most php router-things)

Comment: That helped but now I am receiving a 502 bad gateway on all URLs. I did set root path correctly and I changed fastcgi_pass to the correct php fpm sock.